# Prove that the matrices $H_\phi^{(n)}$ and $H_\psi^{(n)}$ are similar.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, similar-matrices

For any map $f: \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$ and any strictly positive integer $n$, We denote by $H_f^{(n)}$ the matrix of $\mathcal{M}_n$ given by:
$$
H_f^{(n)}=(f(i + j -2))_{1\leq i,j\leq n} =
$$
Let $n\geq 3$ and $\phi$ and $\psi$ are  the functions defined on $\mathbb{N}$ by:
$$
\forall k\in  \mathbb{N},\qquad \phi (k) = (- 1)^ k (k + 1) \qquad,\qquad \psi (k) =k + 1
$$

**Problem**

Prove that the matrices $H_\phi^{(n)}$ and $H_\psi^{(n)}$ are similar.

An idea please

Answer (score 1):

Each entry of $H_\phi^{(n)}$ has the same modulus as its counterpart in $H_\psi^{(n)}$. The only difference between the two matrices is a checkerboard sign pattern. Therefore $H_\phi^{(n)}=DH_\psi^{(n)}D^{-1}$ where $D=D^{-1}=\operatorname{diag}(1,-1,1,-1,\ldots,(-1)^{n-1})$, and the two matrices are similar.

Comment: $$DH_\psi^{(n)}D^{-1}=\left[\begin{matrix} 1&0&\cdots &0\\ 0&-1&\cdots&0\\ \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&\cdots&(-1)^{n-1}
\end{matrix}\right] . \left[\begin{matrix} 1&2&\cdots &n\\ 2&3&\cdots&n+1\\ \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\n&n+1&\cdots&2n-1
\end{matrix}\right].  \left[\begin{matrix} 1&0&\cdots &0\\ 0&-1&\cdots&0\\ \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&\cdots&(-1)^{n-1}
\end{matrix}\right]=H_\psi^{(n)}\neq H_\phi^{(n)} $$

Comment: @Made $\pmatrix{1\\ &-1}\pmatrix{1&2\\ 2&3}\pmatrix{1\\ &-1}=\pmatrix{1&2\\ -2&-3}\pmatrix{1\\ &-1}=\pmatrix{1&-2\\ -2&3}$.